# Handle bars interprets the number as a string and doesn't return the entire string instead it truncates when it has space in it

Tags: java, angular, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, handlebars.java

I am using Java 8 and Handlebars version 4.1.2.

I am sending numbers as a string from UI and the handlebars are not returning the entire string in it.

Here are the scenarios which are failing:

**Issue1:**

Numbers followed by space followed by text (alphabets or numbers or special characters). In this case, only the starting number is displayed

- Ex 1: `102 somename` - only 102 is displayed.
- Ex 2: `100 009` -  only 100 is displayed

**Issue2:**

Text within double quotes followed by text. In this case only string within the text is displayed.

- Ex 1: `"title Fix" count` - "title Fix" is displayed

But this should not be the case, they should display as `102 somename`, `100 009`, `"title Fix" count`.

I have been trying with multiple versions of handlebars but none worked.

Here is my file content:

Hbs file content:

{
"title":  "{{#escapeSpecialCharactersForTitle title}}{{/escapeSpecialCharactersForTitle}}"

}

Helper class:

public static void registerEscapeSpecialCharactersForTitle(Handlebars handlebars) {

```
    handlebars.registerHelper("escapeSpecialCharactersForTitle",
            (str,options) -> {
                if(str!= null && !isEmpty(str.toString())) {
                    String title = str.toString();
                    escapeAllSpecialCharacatersFromString(title);
                    String finalString = JSONValue.toJSONString(title);
                    return finalString;
                }
                return "";
            });
}

public static void escapeAllSpecialCharacatersFromString(String finalString) {
     String[] specialCharacters = {"^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","*","+","?","|","<",">","-","&","%","'","\\","/","="};

    for(int i=0;i<specialCharacters.length;i++) {
        if(finalString.contains(specialCharacters[i])) {
            finalString = finalString.replace(specialCharacters[i],"\\"+specialCharacters[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And FYI, for the text which includes quotes (""), I am  escaping the double quotes So from UI its sent as \"title Fix\" count

Comment: I can think of no reason why a portion of a string after a space would get chopped-off.

Comment: but in my scenario I have a custom helper function created where we pass the text with specialCharacters to escape them and handlebar internally assumes the string as a IntNode and truncates anything beyond the number for that , example 123 123

Comment: Then I think you should share the code of your custom helper.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the custom helper code under the question details.

Comment: Why are you using this helper as a Block Helper (ie., `{{#escapeSpecialCharactersForTitle title}}` - starting with the '#'). It doesn't look like you want this to be a Block Helper.

Comment: I will need to use the blockHelper here based on my project structure. Anyway, even without that helper call in hbs file, I still receive the truncated string in case of 100 009 as 100

Comment: If the problem is not with the helper then it must be somewhere else in your code and so I don't think I will be able to help you.